# Project on Maven is not importing its dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have this new project in Maven, the dependencies in pom.xml appears in the maven dependency folder, but the import in the classes give the message "cannot be resolved".

[image]

Comment: Post the `pom.xml` and tell us if it works when you do `mvn clean install` from console?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of missing setting.xml file in your settings of eclipse or internet download not working, pls. check them.

Comment: What do you meant with missing settings.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do this operation, refresh your project, it should work.

Comment: I tried Update but it didn't work, but restarting eclipse fixed the problem.